# How to obtain installed package files?

Tags: apt, package-management

I need to download all packages I already installed on Ubuntu 11.10 x64. There should be in `/var/cache/apt/archives` I know, but there are only 300 Mb of deb files. I installed a lot of development packages that there are not there right now. I think system cleans the cache automatically!

Now I want to download all packages installed on system, else than packages that are installed by default.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following command in the terminal grabs the list of installed packages and downloads, packages will be stored at /var/cache/apt/archives

```
dpkg -l | grep "^ii"| awk ' {print $2} ' | xargs sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall --download-only
```

Comment: Can re-installation cause some problem in system? like missing configuration of packages?

Comment: Oh! the `--download-only` flag... Thanks :-)

Comment: I run this command but my system hanged after running it for 1 hour and i restart the system, Do I have to start again or some of packages will be work on other system when i copy and run?

Comment: I get messages like `Reinstallation of chroot is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.`...