# installed package on offline system

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I have two system

```
A: Ubuntu 14.04 with internet 
B: Ubuntu 14.04 without internet
```

I have customized and installed missing files and packages on **A**. Now I  need to enable  to play `.mp3` files on **B**

How do I do that? overall I want to know

- How to install missing packages, in some zip or any package system?
- How do I distribute the packege  or it will done by single command?

**UPDATE**

I run below command from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/86413/133785)

```
dpkg -l | grep "^ii"| awk ' {print $2} ' | xargs sudo apt-get -y install --reinstall --download-only
```

now what to do?

Please help.

Comment: Which package would help...

Comment: You should have Rhythmbox installed.

Comment: I read those duplicates but there are few confusing points :|

Comment: @diEcho Regarding your UPDATE edit dated August 18, 2014: Look at the first paragraph of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline/1016#1016) to one of the two duplicate questions mentioned above. First of all, you will also need to install Synaptic Package Manager in the other computer somehow or another.

Comment: that **somehow** is confusing. How can I install syanptic manager without internet, if internet is possible I can download ubuntu restricted extras from software centre, isn't it?

Comment: Isn't there any simple method/approach? so that I can collect all necessary packages which I have installed on system A and distribute on system B.